# Compass ERROR: no implicit conversion of Array into String

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, compass-sass, compass

I´m trying to use Compass inside my Rails application for CSS Sprites, but after insert the path of my icons inside my SCSS file I receive the error below:

"in implicit conversion of Array into String"

This is my code:

custom.css.scss

@import "../icons/*.png"; // only this line causes the problem :(
@include all-icons-sprites;

I have 4 files inside this directory: add.png, delete.png, settings.png and new.png.

Answer (score 2):

> The import statement needs to be relative to your images directory, it's not relative to your sass file.

https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1879